# Hardcode the date value in Query SSRS

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query which I am trying to hard code the date value. Currently this data is coming from SSRS Calendar. I think my data is coming little different than expected. To debug all the things I need to hard code the date section.

How can I take care of these things? I am new to SQL and SSRS.

```
WITH Calendar (Start_Date, End_Date) AS(
Select TOP 6
DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @StartDate) -6 + Row_Number() Over (Order By CI_ID), 0)),0)[Start_Date],
DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @StartDate) -6 + Row_Number() Over (Order By CI_ID), 0))+1,0)) [End_Date] 
From v_UpdateInfo
Group by CI_ID
)
Select Start_Date, End_Date,
(Select count(distinct ucs.ResourceID)
From v_Update_ComplianceStatus ucs
JOIN v_UpdateInfo ui on ui.CI_ID = ucs.CI_ID and ucs.Status = 2 AND ui.IsSuperseded = 0
JOIN v_CICategoryInfo_All cica JOIN v_CategoryInfo ci on cica.CategoryInstanceID = ci.CategoryInstanceID AND cica.CategoryInstanceName IN (@Category) on ucs.CI_ID = cica.CI_ID
Where ucs.ResourceID IN (Select rs.ResourceID from v_r_system  rs   JOIN V_FullCollectionMembership AS FCM on rs.ResourceID = FCM.ResourceID and FCM.CollectionID = @CollectionID  JOIN v_UpdateScanStatus uss on uss.ResourceID = rs.ResourceID where rs.Operating_System_Name_and0 like '%Workstation 6.1%' And DATEDIFF("d",uss.LastScanTime,getdate()) <= @DaysScanned AND rs.Obsolete0 = 0 )
AND ui.DateRevised BETWEEN cal.Start_Date AND cal.End_Date
) [Windows 7],
(Select count(rs.ResourceID) from v_r_system rs JOIN V_FullCollectionMembership AS FCM on rs.ResourceID = FCM.ResourceID and FCM.CollectionID = @CollectionID  JOIN v_UpdateScanStatus uss on uss.ResourceID = rs.ResourceID where rs.Operating_System_Name_and0 like '%Workstation 6.3%' And DATEDIFF("d",uss.LastScanTime,getdate()) <= @DaysScanned AND rs.Obsolete0 = 0) [Windows 8.1 Total],
(Select count(distinct ucs.ResourceID)
From v_Update_ComplianceStatus ucs
JOIN v_UpdateInfo ui on ui.CI_ID = ucs.CI_ID and ucs.Status = 2 AND ui.IsSuperseded = 0
JOIN v_CICategoryInfo_All cica JOIN v_CategoryInfo ci on cica.CategoryInstanceID = ci.CategoryInstanceID AND cica.CategoryInstanceName IN (@Category) on ucs.CI_ID = cica.CI_ID
Where ucs.ResourceID IN (Select rs.ResourceID from v_r_system rs    JOIN V_FullCollectionMembership AS FCM on rs.ResourceID = FCM.ResourceID and FCM.CollectionID = @CollectionID  JOIN v_UpdateScanStatus uss on uss.ResourceID = rs.ResourceID where rs.Operating_System_Name_and0 like '%Workstation 10%' And DATEDIFF("d",uss.LastScanTime,getdate()) <= @DaysScanned AND rs.Obsolete0 = 0 )
AND ui.DateRevised BETWEEN cal.Start_Date AND cal.End_Date
) [Windows 10],
(Select count(rs.ResourceID) from v_r_system rs JOIN V_FullCollectionMembership AS FCM on rs.ResourceID = FCM.ResourceID and FCM.CollectionID = @CollectionID  JOIN v_UpdateScanStatus uss on uss.ResourceID = rs.ResourceID where rs.Operating_System_Name_and0 like '%Workstation 10%' And DATEDIFF("d",uss.LastScanTime,getdate()) <= @DaysScanned AND rs.Obsolete0 = 0) [Windows 10 Total]
from Calendar cal
```

So, far i tried this.

```
Declare start_date = '2019-06-01';
declare end_date = '2019-11-30';
    --WITH Calendar (Start_Date, End_Date) AS(
    Select TOP 6
    DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @StartDate) -6 + Row_Number() Over (Order By CI_ID), 0)),0)[Start_Date],
    DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @StartDate) -6 + Row_Number() Over (Order By CI_ID), 0))+1,0)) [End_Date] 
    From v_UpdateInfo
    Group by CI_ID
    )
    Select Start_Date, End_Date,
    (Select count(distinct ucs.ResourceID)
    From v_Update_ComplianceStatus ucs
    JOIN v_UpdateInfo ui on ui.CI_ID = ucs.CI_ID and ucs.Status = 2 AND ui.IsSuperseded = 0
    JOIN v_CICategoryInfo_All cica JOIN v_CategoryInfo ci on cica.CategoryInstanceID = ci.CategoryInstanceID --AND 
    --cica.CategoryInstanceName -- IN (@Category) 
    on ucs.CI_ID = cica.CI_ID
    Where ucs.ResourceID IN (Select rs.ResourceID from v_r_system  rs   JOIN V_FullCollectionMembership AS FCM on rs.ResourceID = FCM.ResourceID
     and FCM.CollectionID = 'ABC0028'  JOIN v_UpdateScanStatus uss on uss.ResourceID = rs.ResourceID 
     where rs.Operating_System_Name_and0 like '%Workstation 6.1%' And DATEDIFF("d",uss.LastScanTime,getdate()) <= @DaysScanned AND rs.Obsolete0 = 0 )
    AND ui.DateRevised BETWEEN cal.Start_Date AND cal.End_Date
    ) [Windows 7],
    (Select count(rs.ResourceID) from v_r_system rs JOIN V_FullCollectionMembership AS FCM on rs.ResourceID = FCM.ResourceID 
    and FCM.CollectionID = 'ABC0028'  JOIN v_UpdateScanStatus uss on uss.ResourceID = rs.ResourceID 
    where rs.Operating_System_Name_and0 like '%Workstation 6.3%' 
    And DATEDIFF("d",uss.LastScanTime,getdate()) <= @DaysScanned AND rs.Obsolete0 = 0) [Windows 8.1 Total],
    (Select count(distinct ucs.ResourceID)
    From v_Update_ComplianceStatus ucs
    JOIN v_UpdateInfo ui on ui.CI_ID = ucs.CI_ID and ucs.Status = 2 AND ui.IsSuperseded = 0
    JOIN v_CICategoryInfo_All cica JOIN v_CategoryInfo ci on cica.CategoryInstanceID = ci.CategoryInstanceID 
    --AND cica.CategoryInstanceName IN (@Category)
     on ucs.CI_ID = cica.CI_ID
    Where ucs.ResourceID IN (Select rs.ResourceID 
    from v_r_system rs  JOIN V_FullCollectionMembership AS FCM on rs.ResourceID = FCM.ResourceID and FCM.CollectionID = 'ABC0028'  
    JOIN v_UpdateScanStatus uss on uss.ResourceID = rs.ResourceID 
    where rs.Operating_System_Name_and0 like '%Workstation 10%' And DATEDIFF("d",uss.LastScanTime,getdate()) <= @DaysScanned AND rs.Obsolete0 = 0 )
    AND ui.DateRevised BETWEEN cal.Start_Date AND cal.End_Date
    ) [Windows 10],
    (Select count(rs.ResourceID) from v_r_system rs JOIN V_FullCollectionMembership AS FCM on rs.ResourceID = FCM.ResourceID and
     FCM.CollectionID = 'ABC0028'  JOIN v_UpdateScanStatus uss on uss.ResourceID = rs.ResourceID where rs.Operating_System_Name_and0 
     like '%Workstation 10%' And DATEDIFF("d",uss.LastScanTime,getdate()) <= @DaysScanned AND rs.Obsolete0 = 0) [Windows 10 Total]
    --from Calendar cal
```

Comment: Have you tried building a date table in your target application, and joining on that? Performance will be much, much better than building the table on every query.

Comment: @OwlsSleeping No i didn't tried to build that as i am accessing SCCM database. Can't create any table there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 date parameters controlling your query. They are `Start_Date` and `End_Date`. You will need to update all references to these in the query. In the original query you posted there are 2 references.

To keep modification to the query minimal all I did in this solution is modify the CTE to use your hard coded dates.

Also, want to note that there are other variables besides the dates in this query that will need to be declared and handled. They are @DaysScanned and @CollectionID. Since you didn't mention them in your OP I am assuming they are not an issue for you.

```
WITH Calendar (Start_Date, End_Date)
AS (SELECT CAST('2019-06-01' AS DATETIME2) AS [Start_Date],
           CAST('2019-11-30' AS DATETIME2) AS [End_Date])
SELECT Start_Date,
       End_Date,
       (
           SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ucs.ResourceID)
           FROM v_Update_ComplianceStatus ucs
               JOIN v_UpdateInfo ui
                   ON ui.CI_ID = ucs.CI_ID
                      AND ucs.Status = 2
                      AND ui.IsSuperseded = 0
               JOIN v_CICategoryInfo_All cica
                   JOIN v_CategoryInfo ci
                       ON cica.CategoryInstanceID = ci.CategoryInstanceID
                          AND cica.CategoryInstanceName IN ( @Category )
                   ON ucs.CI_ID = cica.CI_ID
           WHERE ucs.ResourceID IN
                 (
                     SELECT rs.ResourceID
                     FROM v_r_system rs
                         JOIN V_FullCollectionMembership AS FCM
                             ON rs.ResourceID = FCM.ResourceID
                                AND FCM.CollectionID = @CollectionID
                         JOIN v_UpdateScanStatus uss
                             ON uss.ResourceID = rs.ResourceID
                     WHERE rs.Operating_System_Name_and0 LIKE '%Workstation 6.1%'
                           AND DATEDIFF("d", uss.LastScanTime, GETDATE()) <= @DaysScanned
                           AND rs.Obsolete0 = 0
                 )
                 AND ui.DateRevised
                 BETWEEN cal.Start_Date AND cal.End_Date
       ) [Windows 7],
       (
           SELECT COUNT(rs.ResourceID)
           FROM v_r_system rs
               JOIN V_FullCollectionMembership AS FCM
                   ON rs.ResourceID = FCM.ResourceID
                      AND FCM.CollectionID = @CollectionID
               JOIN v_UpdateScanStatus uss
                   ON uss.ResourceID = rs.ResourceID
           WHERE rs.Operating_System_Name_and0 LIKE '%Workstation 6.3%'
                 AND DATEDIFF("d", uss.LastScanTime, GETDATE()) <= @DaysScanned
                 AND rs.Obsolete0 = 0
       ) [Windows 8.1 Total],
       (
           SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ucs.ResourceID)
           FROM v_Update_ComplianceStatus ucs
               JOIN v_UpdateInfo ui
                   ON ui.CI_ID = ucs.CI_ID
                      AND ucs.Status = 2
                      AND ui.IsSuperseded = 0
               JOIN v_CICategoryInfo_All cica
                   JOIN v_CategoryInfo ci
                       ON cica.CategoryInstanceID = ci.CategoryInstanceID
                          AND cica.CategoryInstanceName IN ( @Category )
                   ON ucs.CI_ID = cica.CI_ID
           WHERE ucs.ResourceID IN
                 (
                     SELECT rs.ResourceID
                     FROM v_r_system rs
                         JOIN V_FullCollectionMembership AS FCM
                             ON rs.ResourceID = FCM.ResourceID
                                AND FCM.CollectionID = @CollectionID
                         JOIN v_UpdateScanStatus uss
                             ON uss.ResourceID = rs.ResourceID
                     WHERE rs.Operating_System_Name_and0 LIKE '%Workstation 10%'
                           AND DATEDIFF("d", uss.LastScanTime, GETDATE()) <= @DaysScanned
                           AND rs.Obsolete0 = 0
                 )
                 AND ui.DateRevised
                 BETWEEN cal.Start_Date AND cal.End_Date
       ) [Windows 10],
       (
           SELECT COUNT(rs.ResourceID)
           FROM v_r_system rs
               JOIN V_FullCollectionMembership AS FCM
                   ON rs.ResourceID = FCM.ResourceID
                      AND FCM.CollectionID = @CollectionID
               JOIN v_UpdateScanStatus uss
                   ON uss.ResourceID = rs.ResourceID
           WHERE rs.Operating_System_Name_and0 LIKE '%Workstation 10%'
                 AND DATEDIFF("d", uss.LastScanTime, GETDATE()) <= @DaysScanned
                 AND rs.Obsolete0 = 0
       ) [Windows 10 Total]
FROM Calendar cal;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes Collection and Category i can manage. Voted Up